# Replace nth string from each line starting from the end

Tags: replace, awk, sed

I have lines that have a variable number of underscores. I need to replace the 3rd underscore starting from the end of the line. Is there a `sed`, `awk` or any other oneliner option?

Example:

```
>ABC_BBB_VVV_BBB_NNN
>ABC_BBB_FFF_VVV_BBB_NNN
```

should turn into

```
>ABC_BBB=VVV_BBB_NNN
>ABC_BBB_FFF=VVV_BBB_NNN
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks for the third `_` from the end and replaces it with a `=`:

```
$ sed -E 's/_([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*)$/=\1/' input
ABC_BBB=VVV_BBB_NNN    
ABC_BBB_FFF=VVV_BBB_NNN
```

This can be slightly shortened to:

```
sed -E 's/_([^_]*(_[^_]*){2})$/=\1/' input
```

The above is for `n=3`.  For other `n`, just replace the `2` with `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to be able to adapt the solution to 2 or 4 or any other number of underscores from either end and using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -F_ '{$0=gensub(FS,"=",NF-3)}1' file
ABC_BBB=VVV_BBB_NNN
ABC_BBB_FFF=VVV_BBB_NNN

$ awk -F_ '{$0=gensub(FS,"=",NF-2)}1' file
ABC_BBB_VVV=BBB_NNN
ABC_BBB_FFF_VVV=BBB_NNN

$ awk -F_ '{$0=gensub(FS,"=",NF-4)}1' file
ABC=BBB_VVV_BBB_NNN
ABC_BBB=FFF_VVV_BBB_NNN
```

Comment: This gives an ungraceful result (warning message) for every line with fewer than expected underscores, e.g. for each blank line. Maybe guard with `NF>n` condition?

Comment: lots of possibilities to deal with if any of that if it can happen but since the OP doesnt show it in their sample input/output....

Answer (score 0):

Or awk:

```
awk -F_ '{for(i=1;i<NF;++i)printf("%s%c",$i,i==NF-3?"=":"_");printf("%s\n",$NF)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/_VVV/,"=VVV")}1' file

>ABC_BBB=VVV_BBB_NNN
>ABC_BBB_FFF=VVV_BBB_NNN
```